# Cannot Add Contributions for Some Contacts

Tags: contributions, mysql, multilingual

I have had and solved an error before where MySQL reports "Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger". However, in those cases the error was for all transactions. I am getting the same error in my logs but only for some contacts and not others.

I am now seeing the problem when a new new contribution is made by a user of the website for a membership. These users do not have CiivCRM or  Drupal admin rights.

I have tried to analyze what is different between contacts that manifest the problem and those that do not. I cannot find a trend. Other contacts that were imported at the time can have donations applied to them, there is no changed based on *Financial Types* or *Payment Method*.

The complete error message coming from the log file in ConfigandLog looks like this:

db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO `civicrm_contribution` (`contact_id` , `financial_type_id` , `payment_instrument_id` , `receive_date` , `non_deductible_amount` , `total_amount` , `fee_amount` , `net_amount` , `trxn_id` , `invoice_number` , `currency` , `cancel_date` , `cancel_reason` , `receipt_date` , `thankyou_date` , `source` , `amount_level` , `is_pay_later` , `contribution_status_id` , `check_number` , `campaign_id` , `tax_amount` ) VALUES ( 84941 ,  4 ,  7 ,  20230108161500 ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  NULL , 'INV_116130' , 'USD' ,  NULL ,  NULL ,  NULL ,  NULL , 'This is a test' , 'Contribution Amount - 1' ,  0 ,  1 ,  NULL ,  NULL ,  0 )  [nativecode=1442 ** Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.]"

I have rebuilt the triggers, deleted the triggers and added them back, and upgragraed CiviCRM to 5.56.2.

The database for Drupal and CiviCRM are hosting on Amazon Aurora (MySQL).  I have turned on audit logs and do not see anything in the logs that help understand this issue.

Any help with figuring this out is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have logging enabled?  If so, try disabling and re-enabling that.  Logging uses triggers.

Comment: @Aidan, thank you for the idea.  We are not using logging because we are in a multilingual environment.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah! It's always worth mentioning that you are running mutlilingual.  That makes various changes to the database schema etc and has various unique 'features'!  I don't use that but I think it has some things implemented with triggers.  I'd suggest updating the question to include this information in case readers don't get as far as these comments.

Comment: barely related, but i spotted on chat a discussion about bgm having a solution for logging on multilanguage sites